# Write the dynamic output of terminal into a text file

Tags: command-line, bash, sound, scripts, sox

It comes down to being able to save the `dynamic output` (I'll explain) of terminal into a text file, but here's what I'm ultimately seeking.

I created a custom command for terminal called `playRandom`, what it does is that it plays random songs forever. The bash file I created for this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
find ./ -type f | sort -R | xargs -I + play +
```

Note: The `play` command is from [SoX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoX) software.

Now the output looks something like this:

[image: playRandom command]

As you can see the output changes `dynamically`, so I cannot use `>>` to save the output.

I want to be able to save 'names of songs that are played' into a text file.

How can I achieve this goal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `play` exit right after file is done if you play just one file ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Yes, but it exits when the song is finished playing.

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani perfect ! I think i can make it work such that it writes out each filename to file before playing. I'll work on a solution, probably will take me 15 -20 minutes. I'll let you know once i post

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani OK, I've posted an answer, covered two cases - outputting currently playing file and outputting whole list before playing the list. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Saving filenames that are played currently

Since the `play` command terminates after playing a single file, what we can do is instead of using `xargs` and giving `play` a batch of files, we'll take out each file, one at a time, and echo it to file, and play the file afterwards. The edited script would look like below. Notice that here are added additional options and `IFS= read -d'' -r` command to deal with filenames in safe manner.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash 

# create file for playing songs first
echo > playlist.txt

# Now play each song and echo filename to file
find ./ -type f -print0 | sort -z -R | while IFS= read -d '' -r filename
do
    clear
    echo "$filename" >> playlist.txt
    play "$filename"
done
```

The advantage of this approach is that filenames will go into playlist.txt  as they are played, which allows us to track output of the script in real time with something like `tail -F playlist.txt`.

**NOTE**: to avoid `playlist.txt` being listed in `find`'s output change `find` command like so:

```
find ./ -type f -not -name "playlist.txt" -print0
```

Additionally if we want to ensure that only `.mp3` files are listed we can do this:

```
find ./ -type f \( -not -name "playlist.txt" -and -name "*.mp3" \) -print0
```

---

#### Saving list of found files to be played

If our goal is to safe the file list *before* it is played, there's not a lot of science to it - the find-sort pipeline can be written to file first, and that file can then be fed to `play` either via `xargs` or again via `while IFS= read -r  ; do ... done` structure

```bsh
#!/bin/bash 

find ./ -type f -print0 | sort -z -R > playlist.txt

while IFS= read -d '' -r filename
do
    clear
    play "$filename"
done < playlist.txt
```

Comment: Your first approach is what I want, thank you :) but there's a [problem](http://imgh.us/Screenshot_from_2017-06-04_02-37-01.png).

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani sorry, there should have been an extra space after `-d` option. I'll fix that in a second.

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani I also noticed that the script finds the `playlist.txt` file, i.e. it finds it's own output.Do you want me to add improvement to script so that the `find` command ignores `playlist.txt` ?

Comment: That would be amazing :))
BTW, now the script works and it's exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani you're welcome , and glad I could help. I've added additional notes on filtering the files with `find`

Comment: There's one more thing; I want it to write the name when the song is finished playing. Which it does, but now when I press `ctrl-c` (which will not end the loop, but will play another random song), it still writes the name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59854/discussion-between-amir-a-shabani-and-sergiy-kolodyazhnyy).

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani hi, Amir. Just wanted to check back with you. I'll see what can be done, but the best way probably would be to kill the script by pid or by `pkill -f script_name.sh`.  I might work on this on the weekend, and maybe will find a better solution.

Comment: Nice solution. One small tweak: When you check `-name '*.mp3'`, you don't need to also check `-not -name 'playlist.txt'`.

Comment: @PaddyLandau yeah, that was redundant. I'll fix it up when I've time or you can edit my answer if you wish.

Answer (score 8):

```
find ./ -type f | sort -R | tee text.file | xargs -I + play +
```

Also see `man tee`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

### 1. Real time (Currently playing)

After you ran the `play` command use this:

```
soxi "$(readlink /proc/`pidof play`/fd/3)" | grep -Po "(?<=Title=).*"
```

It will returns the currently playing song's name for you and you are able to redirect it to a file using `>`.

#### 1.1. Notes

```
/proc/`pidof play`/fd/3
```

- is the file descriptor to your current playing track (file).
- using `readlink` we get the file name
- using `soxi` we get its information
- using `grep` we cut the track title

---

### 2. Before playing (List all names)

```
find ./ -type f | sort -R | tee /tmp/play-files | xargs -I + soxi "+"\
| grep -Po "(?<=Title=).*" > list_of_names && xargs < /tmp/play-files\
-I + play "+"
```

It will create a file named `list_of_names` in your current directory which contains all track names.